# Form submission parameters in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, forms

Is there any way or any extension for chrome through which i can check what form parameters are submitted when a form is submitted.

for example

```
<form action="post.php" type="post">
<input name="fname" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

so i want to see the value of text field whenever the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if it is ajax submission of form using jquery $.ajax, then you carryout following steps to see the form data:

1. right click > inspect element > network tab
2. here the last request will be the "post" or "get" request you did using ajax
3. click on the request and right side you will get the "form data" information

If it is not ajax submission then you need to check it at the back-end ( in the function to which the form data is sent ).

PHP : you can just do print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST) to see the data posted to your function from your browser form.

Comment: Actually the file to which i'm posting is not on my server. I just want to reverse engineer form submission of some other website for educational purpose only.

Comment: You can write some javascript in the console to stop the form submission and instead show what is getting submitted. Use something like this in jquery if available:

$("form").submit(function(){ console.log($(this).serialize()); });